# Can you vote on a moderator's moderating?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderation

Is it possible to vote on a moderators moderating?

Comment: Why do you think reasking this question with a single sentence will do any better here than you did on the [main Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268064/is-there-any-way-to-up-vote-or-down-vote-moderators)?

Comment: Short answer:  no.  Long answer:  if you see a moderator *flagrantly* abusing their powers, you can [follow these instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28869/175248) and get some recourse for it.

Comment: I think this would be fruitless.  If it were done, honestly, people would only vote when they were unhappy with a moderator's actions, ever based on positive activities.

Comment: To be fair, this single sentence is a vast improvement over that MSE non feature request @animuson.

Answer (score 11):

Totally - you vote *with your actions!*

The bulk of the moderation here is done by folks just like you. So if you think it's being done well, you can help out by voting and editing in kind. If you think it's being done wrong, then you can step up to correct it.

As part of the moderation team on Stack Overflow, it's on you to make sure you take action whenever you see something wrong. Your voice will only go unheard if you refuse to act...